# Use git diff to show only whitespace errors as defined in .gitattributes?

Tags: git, git-diff, gitattributes

In `.gitattributes` I define what sorts of whitespaces should `git diff` treat as errors, for example:

```rb
*.xml whitespace=trailing-space,space-before-tab,indent-with-non-tab,tabwidth=2
```

The `whitespace` in this example option tells that `git diff` should treat specified kinds of whitespaces as errors for `xml` files.

When `git diff` is run against some `xml` file and finds those whitespace problems it will mark them with red background color, in the example bellow there are multiple whitespaces before tab as they are marked with red square for all the whitespaces:

[image]

What I want to achieve with `git diff` is to show me **ONLY lines whitespace errors** and no other code changes, is that possible and how?

Code changes which contain no whitespace errors should not be shown to reduce output only to whitespace errors.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this with `git diff`. You can, however, get the same messages from `git apply`, minus the fancy coloring (all you get is the line numbers).

Comment: I never in my life used `git apply` and don't know how it works but will test it, can you run `git apply` on unstaged files without staging them and without automatically fixing whitespace errors?

Comment: It has a dry-run mode. I don't remember for sure if that prints whitespace error messages, but it's worth a try.